# Websphere profile creation issue

Tags: websphere

I was trying to create a new profile with Profile Management Tool. However I am stuck at the step "Port value Assignment".

I cannot go to next. Finish button is grayed out. Next button is highlighted but it does not do anything when I click. I dont see any warning or error.

I thought the port may be conflicting but in that case I see an error message showing above. But this does not show anything and I am not sure what to do now. I am new to Websphere. I want to have Admin Console and all. So I am guessing I would get those once I have a profile created.A help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  I found that if you run the WebSphere Profile Management Tool as Administrator on Windows that you get past this screen.

To do this close the tool, then navigate using the Start menu: Start > All programs > IBM WebSphere Application Server v9.0 then right click on "Profile Management Tool" and select "Run as administrator" from the pop-up menu.  Then proceed as normal.

This assumes you have administrator privilege on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the logs, which should be located at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\workspaces\WCT90\.metadata\.plugins` in either the `com.ibm.ws.pmt.tools` directory or the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` directory. If there's a message being emitted when you click next, it might help work around the problem or ask for help.

If you can't work around it, you can follow [this article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/tpro_setup.html) to create a profile using the command-line utilities. It uses the manageprofiles command which is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/rxml_manageprofiles.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding the Dmgr profile using command line:

`manageprofiles.bat -create -defaultPorts -profileName Dmgr01 -adminUserName wasadmin -adminPassword p@ssword -enableAdminSecurity true  -profilePath PATHOFWAS\profiles\Dmgr01 -templatePath PATHOFWAS\profileTemplates\dmgr -serverType DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER -cellName localhostCell01 -hostName localhost -nodeName localhostNode01`

You  should get an INSTCONSUCCESS message if the creation success

Comment: I  am getting an error saying "No profile template exists at path..."

Answer (score 0):

I ran application as a regular user and checked logs in Profile Management Tool, and there is NullPointerException while tool tries to create the file with configuration. I think this is application bug.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue came and was solved. follow below steps
go to Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin
and run command "manageprofiles.bat -create".
refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52581_01/rtd.320/e52406/websphere8.htm#BIRIA1773 for more info.